# skip white space by reading characters

Tags: c#

I want to skip the white space between characters. For example, I have this:

`abc def ghi`, then the output has to be:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1..etc
```

but now I get:

```
"" = 2.
```

Because there are two white spaces between the characters.

I try it like this:

```
SortedDictionary<char, int> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: "); // prompt for user input
string input = Console.ReadLine(); // get input

// split input text into tokens
char[] letters = Regex.Split(input.ToCharArray().ToString(), @"\s+");
```

Comment: `Regex.Split` returns a `string[]` not a `char[]`.  If you want all the characters in a string then you want `char[] letters = input.ToArray()`.  Are you just trying to count how many of each character exists in the `string`? Can you please give a full expected output for your input.

Comment: you want to skip white spaces. then what is `a = 1`, `b = 1`? sorry but i didnt get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just omit the spaces from your array:

```
using System.Linq;

// Your other code
char[] letters = input.Where(c => c != ' ').ToArray();
```

A string is inherently a `char` array, so you don't need to cast it with that call.

Comment: Thank you, but then I will get this error: 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'char'

Comment: Where do you get that error? `input.Where()` will return an `IEnumerable<char>`, and `.ToArray()` turns that into a `char[]`. You can always change the type of `letters` to `var` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to split by matching a pattern:

```
var pattern = @"\s+";
char[] letters = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Aggregate(String.Concat).ToCharArray();
```